# Import Array to Acces 2013

Tags: python, ms-access

i´m trying to make a file sorting database in Access and i know how to INSERT one word in to one cell/column.

```
import pypyodbc

con = pypyodbc.connect("DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;PageTimeout=5;MaxScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;FIL=MS Access;DriverId=25;DefaultDir=C:/Users/Kaiser/Desktop/AccessSPA;DBQ=C:/Users/Kaiser/Desktop/AccessSPA/UDC1.accdb")

cursor = con.cursor()

#cursor.execute(''' DELETE FROM tblLogfile where RDBID = xx''')
cursor.execute(''' INSERT INTO tblLogfile (Filename) VALUES ('test')''')

cursor.commit()

cursor.close()
con.close()
```

But how do i INSERT a whole array of words? i have a array with filename and filedate that i want to INSERT into my database. One column with alla filenames and column with the corresponding filedate. exampel code below

```
import pypyodbc

con = pypyodbc.connect("DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;PageTimeout=5;MaxScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;FIL=MS Access;DriverId=25;DefaultDir=C:/Users/Kaiser/Desktop/AccessSPA;DBQ=C:/Users/Kaiser/Desktop/AccessSPA/UDC1.accdb")

array1 = [] # filenames 
array2 = [] # filedate

cursor = con.cursor()

#cursor.execute(''' DELETE FROM tblLogfile where RDBID = xx ''')
cursor.execute(''' INSERT INTO tblLogfile (Filename, Filedate) VALUES (array1, array2)''')

cursor.commit()

cursor.close()
con.close()
```

i would appreciate the help, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One simple method is to loop the arrays and insert one record for each pair of elements of the arrays.

Comment: yeah, i tried that but cant work out the syntax for "sending" it to acces, thats the problem... @Gustav

Comment: I don't follow. You can insert one record, so what's the trouble putting that into a loop?